# Bootstrap col-lg-6 not using 6 columns but whole row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following Bootstrap 3.2 markup. I want to have this particular row to space into 2 columns of 6 spaces. The following doesn't work (it displays on 2 rows) and I can't figure out by reading the 3.2 documentation on the Grid system:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AppName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AppName)
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HarmonyTarget)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HarmonyTarget)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your window/viewport size. The `col-lg-*` class is meant for displays/windows/viewports equal to or larger than 1200px in width.

If the dispaly or window you're using these with is ever smaller than that, they'll wrap onto their own rows.

Two solutions:

1) Add the next size down for each displays size. This will scale it to the appropriate resolution.

```css
.first {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
.second {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 first">
      Test
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 second">
      Test
    </div>
  </div>
```

2) If you always want it to be two, 6 column grids, simply use the `col-xs-6` class and it'll always be two, 6 column grids at any page size.

```css
.first {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
.second {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 first">
      Test
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 second">
      Test
    </div>
  </div>
```

Unless you need columns to be placed on different rows as the page scales, I recommened option two.

Comment: No problem. The documentation for the grid system has a very nice table showing what happens with each size level of the grid. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid. Definitely worth looking over.

Comment: Note that `class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"` is equivalent to the much simpler `class="col-xs-6"`

Comment: I know, I was just presenting both possibilities. They do act a tad bit different when you cross each if the width thresholds.